# Using Dependency Injection with .NET Core Class Library (.NET Standard)

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2017

I have gone through the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection

and learnt that how I can use dependency injection for Web API.

As mentioned in the above link I can use Startup (Startup.cs) class for dependency injection inside API layer. But how can achieve dependency injection for the .NET Core Class Library. Below is the screenshot how I am adding a class library.
 [image]

And my project structure is

[image]

In the project “DataManagement.Repository” I have written a class “UserRepository” and in the project “DataManagement.Repository.Interfaces” written an Interface “IUserRepository”.

In the project “DataManagement.Business” I have written a class “UserManager”

```
class UserManager
    {
        private IUserManager _userManager;
        public UserManager(IUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
    }
```

As you can see that I am trying to achieve dependency injection through the constructor.

But I am not sure that what changes need to be done for enabling dependency injection inside .NET Core Class Library (.NET Standard).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You don't have to do anything in your class library. Only the main application has a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (earliest point in an application lifecycle you can set up your object graph).

This happens in `Startup.cs` in your ASP.NET Core application. There you also register your dependencies:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserManager,UserManager>();
```

That's it. Class libraries don't have a composition root. Neither they should, because you can't use them without an application and the IoC Container used is a choice of the application not of the library.

You can however provider convenience methods to do this registrations, like the `AddXxx` method common in ASP.NET Core or some kind of module system, like in 3rd party IoC containern like Autofac or Castle Windsor.

Comment: as u said in answer, if  i add this dependency in `Startup.cs` om asp.net core application and then i add it's reference to .NetCore class library, i can use it?

Comment: Yes, if you use dependency injection all the way (and never instantiate a service `new`) it will work

Comment: I asked a question about this subject in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342064/using-ihostingenvironment-in-netcore-library` plz give me help if u can. thanks

Comment: Does the .Api project then have to have a reference to the .Repository project in order to access the implementations of the .Repository interfaces?

Comment: @WillC: Yea, since your composition root is the web application. You can abstract it a bit away, using Extension methods (such as ASP.NET Core does with the `.AddXyz` where you do the registrations within the .AddXyz` Method.

Comment: You can additionally hide transitive dependencies with `<ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />` (by adding `PrivateAssets="All"` to the reference (in your `Xyz.Extensions.DependencyInjection` project that contains the `.AddXyz`method). This will hide the concrete implementations in your main application, so `new ServiceA()` will result in an error, so people won't accidentally. See https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2313#issuecomment-306247396

Comment: my composition root is an api, where i load a plugin (dynamically). Now this plugin uses some library as nuget, how can i in this situation do registration for dependencies required by library ?