# Using IHostingEnvironment in .NetCore library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I build an ASP.NET Core application and I create a .NET Core Class Library for unit testing.

I want to use `IHostingEnvironment` in my library (to get physical path of a file), so I've added this line to Startup.cs of my ASP.NET Core application :

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>();
```

In the Library I've added reference to my ASP.NET application, and in my class I wrote this:

```cs
private IHostingEnvironment _env;
public Class1(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}
```

But when I run it then it gives me this error:

> the following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture date : IHostingEnvironment env

What is the problem?
How can I use it in .NET Core Class Library?

---

EDIT: I tried to use this too:

```cs
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>();
IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
IHostingEnvironment service = provider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
var p = service.WebRootPath;
```

The last one gives me this error:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'

Comment: Unit Test projects are applications, not libraries. UnitTests must be targeting `netcoreapp1.x`, not `netstandard1.x"

Comment: I do according to  this link  `https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html`

Comment: That link also says `"netcoreapp1.0"` and this builds it as application, not class library. xunit doesn't work with `netstandard1.x` (which is what you get in project.json when you create a class library)

Comment: Yes exactly its an application, please see my update, i try another way, but it does not work too.

Comment: I don't think you should register IHostingEnvironment with DI yourself it should already be there, it gets injected into the Startup constructor so it must already be in DI. I've been able to take a dependency on it in my class library projects with no issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: `services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>();` means you are registering `IHostingEnvironment` as an implementation for `IHostingEnvironment` in a singleton scope (always reuse).

Since you can't create an instance of an interface, you get this error.

### solution

define the class you want to be created (that implements `IHostingEnvironment`), eg:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(new HostingEnvironment());
```

### Behind the scenes dotnet core (Hosting nuget package)

In the `WebHostBuilder` The first row in the constructor is:

```
this._hostingEnvironment = (IHostingEnvironment) new HostingEnvironment();
```

This hosting environment is later filled with more settings, by the webhost builder.

You should look at their github page or decompile the sources: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting

Note: Most of the properties/settings of `HostingEnvironment` are set on `Build()` method of the `WebHostBuilder`. If you want to moq/test this yourself you should set these properties yourself or just also include the `WebHostBuilder` in your test.

Comment: why `service.WebRootPath` give me null?

Comment: Because this is also later initialized: see `HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(...)` in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal`. It is called on `WebHostBuilder.Build()` => `private this,BuildCommonSerivces()` => `Initialize()`

Comment: Im going wrong? Do u have suggestion that how can i getwebRootPath?

Comment: Instead of making your class library dependent on Hosting nuget package. give your class library its own [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects), and configure the options in your startup project.

Answer (score 5):

For my .net class library all I had to do is install the following nuget package for version 2.1.0:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/

and then I just injected IHostingEnvironment into my constructor.

I didn't even need to modify Startup.cs

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in both .net core class library and console application:

Using references,

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
```

Adding DI registration,

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment, HostingEnvironment>();
```

Answer (score 2):

*A note for reference as I ended up here.*

If you target **netstandard** (netstandard2.0) in your class library, add Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions from NuGet to get the IHostingEnvironment interface without any implementations.

*I know question specifies .net core, anyways.. might help out those being where I were.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its simple enough

```
private IHostEnvironment env;
public Startup(IHostEnvironment env)
{
    this.env = env;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(env);
}
```

then you can use it in your class

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;
public Class1(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}
```

hope it does the job ^_^